# Why Google Maps code can be blocked with an API key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google Maps API key with this code for showing a map.
I tried to paste it as an example from their site.
but when pasting on a page, a map is not visible.

```html
<iframe
  width="450"
  height="250"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/MAP_MODE?key=KEY"
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter,
    url: '/',
    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
});

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom: 14,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {window.location.href = marker.url;});

</script>
```

It's not clear why, I tried on many hosts. It's an official example
The error is Google:

Site [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is blocked
Site [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) doesn't allow to set a connection

ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

I want to get a map on this page with main elements
I tried many hosts, browsers, can API key be tunable here?
There's an error without map - Google blocked

```
Errors from console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at i.html:10:14
chromewebdata/:1 
       
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
chromewebdata/:1 
        
       Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
(index):1957 
        
       crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):1957
```

Comment: You'll need your own API key.

Comment: I assume you have pasted your actual key in place of `KEY` in the example?

Comment: Yes, I've pasted it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there additional information about the error in the console? If yes, please add it to the question.

Comment: Yes, there is. Here is the Edge console log.

Comment: Is there a way without iframes?